# Filling gaps in hardwood floor - what's the easiest way?

Tags: floor, hardwood

I've got an old, beat-to-hell, hardwood floor in my apartment in the kitchen where quite a bit of water ends up on the floor on a daily basis as there's obvious things like a stove and sink, but also a bathtub/shower in the room. As a result of all the water the hardwood floors have developed quite a few gaps between the floor boards. I'd like to fill these gaps and seal them off as easily as possible. How it will look when it's finished is unimportant to me - I just want to know what the easiest way to do it is. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: how wide and deep are the gaps?

Comment: Hey Shirlock - thank you for responding. The gaps vary from being very shallow and barely noticeable, to being deep, to being completely open with the fill between the boards completely knocked out.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for fast, cheap, easy -- lay a single solid piece of linoleum over the hardwood.  Best to leave the hardwood alone in case someone wants to repair it properly in the future!